# unable to install appium.exe,showing .Net framework Initialisation error

Tags: appium

While installing `appium.exe` in my Windows 7 32 bit laptop.. I am getting

```
.Net Framework Initialization Error..
```

How to solve this error..?

I am installing this appium for testing android applications.

Comment: That sounds like a very generic error. Is there any more information you can provide about the error? If nothing is immediately obvious, you may also want to check the event log.

Answer (score 1):

Appium for windows require .net framework.
You can download the same from the link below.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, .net framework 4.5 fixed the issue for me.